# How to show fully candlestick bars (right and left side) when using Dygraph in R

Tags: r, dygraphs, candlestick-chart

I found out the Dygraph is very nice to plot a Candlestick chart in R. However, it seems that there is a bug when showing the right and the left candlestick bars as can be seen in the picture.

[image: Chart don't show completely candle sticks on the rightest and leftnest]

So could you please show me how to increase the right and left margin in order that the candlestick bars could be seen completely.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: `dyAxis("x", valueRange = c(start, end))` or `dyRangeSelector()`

Comment: So many thanks, Ryan! the solution of using dyRangeSelector() does help.